# Could we get a better error message for attempting to comment while logged out?

Tags: feature-request, comments, wording

If you logout from site, but still have another opened tab in browser with a question, and try to comment you will get this error message:

> [image: not have permission]

Is there any reason to use "User" instead of "you"? Could we change this text to reflect restrictions for the current user (i.e. *you*), not for some other user?

Comment: Ideally, the message will say something like "You must login in order to comment". The current form isn't really helpful to begin with.

Comment: @ShadowWizard to comment everywhere you need a [privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), hence logging in is not enough.

Comment: But it's the first step.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure that we need to say to already logged user about logging if he doesn't have privilege to comment. Perhaps there are should be several versions of the message.

Comment: Anonymous user got some right too, not to comment, but it can be confusing as the system don’t know if you wanted to do something as an anonymous user, in such case the error message displayed is ok. I would suggest to change the message to ´Anonymous user can’t... Please login if you have an account’

Comment: "You must be logged in with an account with at least 50 reputation to post comments."?